# How to enable Flash player in Opera without installing the Adobe bloatware

Tags: flash, plugins, opera, bloatware

I just want to be able to play Youtube videos in Opera 12.

I copied np32dsw.dll in Program Files/Opera/program/plugins

but it still says missing plugin :(

Is there any way to install the Flash plugin, without having to install the Adobe Flash Player?

It seems to work in Chrome...

plz help

Comment: Good News.  Youtube uses HTML5 video.  If you want to play Flash video from within Opera your only choice is to install Adobe Flash Player and enable the Opera support.

Comment: It says it's missing because the actual Flash Player plug-in is `NPSWF32_xxx.dll` (where `xxx` is the file version).

Answer (score 1):

> It seems to work in Chrome...

That is because Chrome already includes Flash plugin. It doesn't take into account that `np32dsw.dll` file you put in the `plugins` folder.

> I just want to be able to play Youtube videos in Opera 12.

A lot of Youtube videos are play-able in the new HTML5 player. Activate it by going to http://youtube.com/html5 and see if videos play. You don't need Flash Player.

Comment: A lot of other sites, like Bandcamp, do require it, though. And on Opera 12, with HTML5, the videos seem to cut off near the end.

Answer (score 0):

## Manually install the Adobe Flash Player plug-in

<sup>*Tested with Opera 12.17 / Adobe Flash Player 14.0.0.125 on Windows 7 SP1 x86 (32-bit).*</sup>

Getting just the Flash Player plug-in file (and nothing else) requires some work, because it comes bundled with a proprietary setup package which can't be unpacked easily.

To avoid an actual installation you can take advantage of virtualization software. For example you could install the package in a virtual machine, and then copy the required files to the main system. In this case a simpler alternative is to use JauntePE, a [portable application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_applications) creator.

1. Log on with an administrator account, and get the latest [standalone Flash Player installer](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/distribution3.html).
2. Download [JauntePE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jauntepe/), and extract its archive somewhere, e.g. through [7-Zip](http://7zip.org/).
3. Close all open browser windows.
4. Right-click the JauntePE executable file, and choose **Run as administrator** from the context menu.
5. Click the **Edit > Add App** menu, make sure the **Install** option is selected, and click the **Next** button. Click **Browse** and pick the installer file you downloaded earlier. Click the **Finish** button when done.
6. Right-click the installer item from the **Available Launchers** list, and select **Run**.
7. At this point the Flash Player setup should start. Tick the license agreement check box, and click **Install**. Click **Done** when it has finished.
8. Go back to JauntePE, and select the **Package Contents** tab. Navigate to the following path:

   ```
   Windows\Windows System\Macromed\Flash
   ```
9. Right-click the `NPSWF32_xxx.dll` file, and choose **Copy** from the context menu. Exit the program and discard the changes. Then navigate to the Opera plug-in folder, which is usually located here:

   ```
   C:\Program Files\Opera\program\plugins
   ```
10. Paste the copied file into the folder. To verify the plug-in was installed successfully you can visit the following test pages:

    - https://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/
    - http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html

### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot 1]

Comment: Hmm. While the site detection completely messed up on Opera 12 (didn't show a working download button) the standalone Flash Player installer itself worked fine. Thanks for that link!